# Neo4j cypher query fails with unknown syntax error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following paramObj and dbQuery

```
 paramObj = {
                    email:         newUser.email, 
                    mobilenumber:  newUser.telephone,
                    password:      newUser.password,
                    category:      newUser.category,
                    name:          newUser.name,
                    confirmuid:    verificationHash,
                    confirmexpire: expiryDate.valueOf(),
                    rewardPoints:       0, 
                    emailconfirmed:    'false',
                    paramVehicles:      makeVehicleArray,  
                    paramVehicleProps:  vehiclePropsArray
                     }
dbQuery = `CREATE (user:Person:Owner {email:$email})                                    
           SET  user += apoc.map.clean(paramObj, 
                 ['email','paramVehicles','paramVehiclesProps'],[])
           WITH user, $paramVehicles AS vehicles
            UNWIND vehicles AS vehicle
            MATCH(v:Vehicles {name:vehicle}) 
            CREATE UNIQUE (user)-[r:OWNS {since: timestamp()}]->(v)
            RETURN user,r,v`;
```

Then I tried to execute

```
 commons.session
              .run(dbQuery, paramObj)
              .then(newUser => {
                  commons.session.close();
                  if (!newUser.records[0]) {........
```

I am getting

```
Error:  {"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError","name":"Neo4jError"}
```

which doesn't direct me anywhere. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

This is actually the first time I am using the query format `.run(dbQuery, paramObj)` but this format is critical to my use case. I am using Neo4j 3.4.5 community with apoc plugin installed.

Ok...so I followed @inversFalcon suggestion to test in browser and came up with following parameters and query that closely match the ones above:

```
   :params paramObj:[{ email:"xyz123@abc.com", mobilenumber:"8711231234",password:"password1", category:"Owner",name:"Michaell",vehicles:["Toyota","BMW","Nissan"],vehicleProps: [] }]
```

and query

```
PROFILE
CREATE (user:Person:Owner {email:$email})
SET  user += apoc.map.clean($paramObj, ["email","vehicles","vehicleProps"],[])
WITH user, $vehicles AS vehicles
UNWIND vehicles AS vehicle
MATCH(v:Vehicles {name:vehicle})
MERGE (user)-[r:OWNS {since: timestamp()}]->(v)
RETURN user,r,v;
```

Now I get
       Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Can't coerce `List{Map{name -> String("Michaell"), vehicles -> List{String("Toyota"), String("BMW"), String("Nissan")},.......

I also reverted to neo4j 3.2 (re: an earlier post by Mark Needham) and got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You should try doing an EXPLAIN of the query using the browser to troubleshoot it.

A few of the things I'm seeing here:

You're referring to `paramObj`, but it's not a parameter (rather, it's the map of parameters you're passing in, but it itself is not a parameter you can reference in the query). If you need to reference the entire set of parameters being passed in, then you need to use nested maps, and have `paramObj` be a key in the map that you pass as the parameter map (and when you do use it in the query, you'll need to use `$paramObj`)

`CREATE UNIQUE` is deprecated, you should use `MERGE` instead, though be aware that it does behave in a different manner (see the [MERGE documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/) as well as our knowledge base article explaining some of the easy-to-miss details of [how MERGE works](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/)).

Comment: I have edited the question with some of your suggestions now I 
 think we making progress.... but I am now getting coercion errors.

Comment: Also, will apoc.map.clean() or apoc.map.removeKeys() mutate the paramObj making it unusable further on in the query?

Comment: They aren't mutators, they should return a separate map with the changes applied, the original should still be usable

Comment: With the change you applied, `paramObj` now refers to a list, not a map, see those square brackets? Get rid of those

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what caused the coercion error to disappear but it did with the same query and I got a "expected parameter error" this was fixed by using $paramObj.email, etc. so the final query looks like this:

```
CREATE (user:Person:Owner {email: $paramObj.email})
SET  user += apoc.map.clean($queryObj, ["email","vehicles","vehicleProps"],[])
WITH user, $paramObj.vehicles AS vehicles
UNWIND vehicles AS vehicle
MATCH(v:Vehicles {name:vehicle})
MERGE (user)-[r:OWNS {since: timestamp()}]->(v)
RETURN user,r,v;
```

which fixed my original problem of how to remove properties from a map when using SET += map.