# my parameter map is not recognized in neo4j cypher

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

**This question is different in that it is more pointed. The previous question though related had other issues including the apoc implementation. Also the answer was not clear.**

I have a parameter map paramObj (from console.log)

{"email":"xyz@abc.com","password":"password123","category":"Owner","name":"Michael""paramVehicles":["Honda","Chevrolet","BMW"],"paramVehicleProps":[]}

and a cypher query queryDB (from console.log)

```
CREATE (user:Person:Owner {email: $email})
  SET user.name = $name, user.password = $password
  WITH user, $paramVehicles AS vehicles
  UNWIND vehicles AS vehicle
  MATCH(v:Vehicles {name:vehicle})
  MERGE (user)-[r:OWNS {since: timestamp()}]->(v)
  RETURN user,r,v
```

with a session .run(queryDB,paramObj).then.... which works fine. However when I tried to use the paramObj in a SET += $paramObj I get an error

```
CREATE (user:Person:Owner {email: $email})
SET user += $paramObj
WITH user, $paramVehicles AS vehicles
UNWIND vehicles AS vehicle
MATCH(v:Vehicles {name:vehicle})
MERGE (user)-[r:OWNS {since: timestamp()}]->(v)
RETURN user,r,v
```

Error:  {"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing","name":"Neo4jError"}

Other combinations such as SET += paramObj or SET += {paramObj} results in the same error or syntax error. I am using neo4j 3.4.5 with nodejs running on the Neo4j Desktop. This error doesn't occur in the browser only in code. What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neo4j cypher query fails with unknown syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439491/neo4j-cypher-query-fails-with-unknown-syntax-error)

Comment: I believe you already asked this one. As previously answered, `paramObj` is not a key in your parameters map, it's the variable you're using in the javascript code to pass the parameter map to be executed by Neo4j, that parameter name will not be able to be referenced by Cypher. If you want to do this sort of thing, you need to explicitly have `paramObj` as a key in the map that you pass in.

Comment: The reason why it probably worked in the browser was you likely set a `paramObj` parameter.

Comment: @inverseFalcon....the question maybe similar but I still don't have an answer could you please  give an example of your explanation. I should also note that I had this format  .run(querydb, {paramObj: paramObj} ).then  and I got the same errors.

Comment: That's different than what you had in your description. Using `session.run(querydb, {paramObj: paramObj} )` should have worked, as `paramObj` would have then been a key in the parameter map you passed in, and should be referenceable in the Cypher query with `$paramObj`. Note that since you added level of nesting, you would have to reference your other parameters accordingly, as they're now properties of the nested paramObj. For example, since `email` is now a property of the `paramObj`, you would reference it in your query like: `$paramObj.email`

Comment: Finally...The problem was I did not understanding the relationship with the different format of the parameter variables. I finally had them all in sync. The previous question had other variables like the apoc.map.clean procedure which masked the error. I would prefer if the supplied the clarity you did here as an answer so I can accept it.